# php preg_mach a mysql db name

Tags: php, preg-match, mysql

Someone please give me a `preg` for this

```
$tbl = '`db_name`.`tbl_name`';

if(preg_match('????',$tbl)){
   echo 'ye';
}else{
   echo 'no';
}
```

I need the `????` of preg_match, just so:

- starts with ` (this is the mysql_special comma dont know the name)
- Followed by a-z,number,underscores
- followed by ` (mysql)
- seperated by (dot) .
- followed by ` (mysql)
- Followed by a-z,number,underscores
- followed by ` (mysql)

Comment: the "special comma" is a "back-tick"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
preg_match('/^`([a-z0-9_]+)`\\.`([a-z0-9_]+)`$/i', $tbl, $matches);
```

Comment: what about starts with and ends with signs?

Comment: dont think it works `if( preg_match('/^`([a-z0-9_]+)`\.`([a-z0-9_]+)`$/i',$tbl.'') ){
   die('nice');
  }`

Comment: I checked several times - it works perfectly, maybe problem in `?

Comment: You need to escape the backslash I think: `\\.`

Answer (score 1):

```
preg_match('/^`(.*?)`\\.`(.*?)`$/i', $tbl, $matches);
$db = $matches[1];
$table = $matches[2];
```

This is a little more generic.  The `.*?` expression will match all characters until it reaches the character that comes after that expression (in this case, the ` character).